# Why is the rendering-definition of my Mask-Content-Element missing?

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, tx-mask

I have created some CE types with ext:mask and if I insert a CE in the page in the FE this error appears:

> Content Element type "mask_my_own_ce" has no rendering definition!

I have inserted the static template of mask, and just edited the generated fluid template

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Fluid Styled Content` Static Template has to be included before `Mask` Static Template, otherwise no mask-elements are shown.

Comment: I missed the inclusion of FSC-static template in my site-extension. After moving mask static template to last position, it works.

Answer (score 1):

Hej,
did you try to delete the cache in the install tool?